# column to rows and values as new column postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I do have the following table

```
date;registrations;deliveries;confirmation
25.09.19;5;3;2
26.09.19;7;4;1
```

and I need to convert the table as shown below

```
date;funnel;quantity
25.09.19;registration;5
25.09.19;deliveries;3
25.09.19;confirmation;2
26.09.19;registration;7
26.09.19;deliveries;4
26.09.19;confirmation;1
```

can someone give me a hint how to do it using posgresql? thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please post data as text, preferably as valid SQL - [not as paintings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1048572).

Comment: Thank you Bergi. Will modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a union for this:

```
(SELECT date, 'registration'::text AS funnel, registrations AS quantity FROM that_table)
UNION ALL (SELECT date, 'delivery', deliveries FROM that_table)
UNION ALL (SELECT data, 'confirmation', confirmation FROM that_table)
```

Alternatively, a bit more complicated but less repetitive, unnest an array (or actually, two in parallel):

```
SELECT
    date,
    unnest(ARRAY['registration', 'delivery', 'confirmation']::text[]) AS funnel,
    unnest(ARRAY[registrations, deliveries, confirmation]) AS quantity
FROM that_table
```

([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3798dab7cdb845da51d64a1dc3ad3863))